# Select all possible previous array/list elements

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to select in a for loop the `i` element of an array/list and store *up to* the 4 previous elements in a list + the present element. This previous-elements list is thus updated every loop as `i` advances:

```
a=list(range(0,50))

for i in range(0,len(a)-1): 
    previous_4=a[i-4:i+1]
    present_element=a[i]

    print('The present element is {}'.format(present_element))
    print('The previous list is {}'.format(previous_4))
```

My problem is that when running the for loop, the first 4 loops do not store any `previous_4` list, not event the present element, as it is below the 0 index.

```
The present element is 0
The previous list is []
The present element is 1
The previous list is []
The present element is 2
The previous list is []
The present element is 3
The previous list is []
The present element is 4
The previous list is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
The present element is 5
The previous list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I want is an output list of any of the 4-previous elements available in *a* list:

```
    The present element is 0
    The previous list is [0]
    The present element is 1
    The previous list is [0, 1]
    The present element is 2
    The previous list is [0, 1, 2]
    The present element is 3
    The previous list is [0, 1, 2, 3]
    The present element is 4
    The previous list is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    The present element is 5
    The previous list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there any way to tell Python *"catch me any available element of this list up to 4 elements"*?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your slicing `a[i-4:i+1]` is wrong because `i-4` is negative at the 4 first iterations. In Python, negative index refers to the elements starting from the end of your list with `a[-1]` being the last element of the list `a`. Therefore `a[-4:0]` returns an empty list while `a[-4:-1]` would return its 3 last elements. Simply change to

```
previous_4 = a[max(0,i-4):i+1]
```

Comment: That worked more than fine, and it's super elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a=list(range(0,8))
previous_4=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)-1): 
    previous_4.append(i)
    present_element=a[i]
    print('The present element is {}'.format(present_element))
    print('The previous list is {}'.format(previous_4))
    if(len(previous_4)==5):
        previous_4.pop(0)
```

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. `list.pop(0)` is `O(n)` -- the entire list needs to be reallocated. Always avoid `list.pop(0), use a `deque` instead.

Comment: can i use    "    a.remove(a[0])     "

Answer (score 0):

You can just append and pop from the prevous4 list as you itereate through the list

```
from collections import deque
a=list(range(0,50))
previous_4 = deque([])
for i in range(0,len(a)-1): 
    previous_4.append(a[i])
    if len(previous_4) > 5:
        previous_4.popleft()
    present_element=a[i]

    print('The present element is {}'.format(present_element))
    print('The previous list is {}'.format(previous_4))
```

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. `list.pop(0)` is `O(n)` -- the entire list needs to be reallocated. Always avoid `list.pop(0), use a `deque` instead.

Comment: Agreed but, since the previous_4 list is only 5 elements long, this doesn't have the horrible effect that pop(0) usually has, so I did it like this for simplicity

Comment: @FHTMitchell fixed

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     if i < 4: 
         previous_4 = a[ : i+1]
     else:
        previous_4 = a[i-4: i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kefeng91's answer is a good solution (+1) but most of the answers are poor. I'd say there is a better way, the functional way! This is the way I would do it in proper production code. It is efficient, extensible and reusable!

```
import collections

def get_n_at_a_time(itr, n):
    d = collections.deque(maxlen=n)  # double ended queue of fixed size
    for elem in iterable:
        d.append(elem)
        yield tuple(d)

for sublist in get_n_at_time(range(50), 4):
    print('the current sublist is: {}'.format(list(sublist)))
```

outputs

```
the current sublist is: [0]
the current sublist is: [0, 1]
the current sublist is: [0, 1, 2]
the current sublist is: [0, 1, 2, 3]
the current sublist is: [1, 2, 3, 4]
the current sublist is: [2, 3, 4, 5]
the current sublist is: [3, 4, 5, 6]
...
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
a=list(range(0,50))

for i in range(0,len(a)-1): 
    previous_4=a[i-min(4,i):i+1]    #here is the change
    present_element=a[i]

    print('The present element is {}'.format(present_element))
    print('The previous list is {}'.format(previous_4))
```

---

**Explanation:-**

In your code,  `i-4` in `previous_4=a[i-4:i+1]` goes negative which is not wanted.

i.e. it should be

> `a[i-4:i+1]` only if `i>4`
>
> or else simply `a[0:i+1]` or `a[i-i, i+1]`

This is what I have done.